# Computations inside of an IF() Function

Tags: formula, custom-field, datetime

I was trying to add some arithmetic inside of an IF function for a custom formula field and it didn't appear to like the syntax...

> IF(AND(ISPICKVAL( Status,'In Progress'),ISPICKVAL( Priority ,'Critical')), NOW() - .00345, null)

Is there any way of doing something like this using a formula or am I better off implementing this with other functionality?

Comment: I think you need to write it as 0.00345 instead; it otherwise looks okay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @sfdcfox said, it will compile with this:

```
 IF(AND(ISPICKVAL( Status,'In Progress'),ISPICKVAL( Priority ,'Critical')), NOW() - 0.00345, null)
```

Comment: How would I implement multiple IF statements like this one?

Comment: @Santanu Boral how is it different from sfdcfox comment?

Comment: for instance IF(AND(ISPICKVAL( Status,'In Progress'),ISPICKVAL( Priority ,'high')), NOW() - 0.0069, null)

Comment: @VanAlfredo use nested `IF` formulas or `CASE`, it depend

Comment: IF(AND(ISPICKVAL(Status,'In Progress'),ISPICKVAL( Priority ,'Critical'),ISPICKVAL(Sub_Status_APS__c  ,'Care')), NOW() - 0.00345,
IF(AND(ISPICKVAL(Status,'In Progress'),ISPICKVAL( Priority ,'High'),ISPICKVAL(Sub_Status_APS__c  ,'Care')),NOW() - 0.005175,
IF(AND(ISPICKVAL(Status,'In Progress'),ISPICKVAL( Priority ,'Medium'),ISPICKVAL(Sub_Status_APS__c  ,'Care')),NOW()- 0.0138,null)))

Comment: Would something like this work or is there a better way?